# eBay API RelistFixedPriceItem vs AddFixedPriceItem when updating quantity

Tags: ebay-api

I am building a system that publishes products from our inventory to our eBay seller account. Everything is working fine, but I just keep thinking which call should I use when I update the quantity in our inventory.

`RelistFixedPriceItem` and `AddFixedPriceItem` both are working well, except that on eBay I will have same item with two different `itemID`, one is sold and one is active...
is that ok? Does it have something to do with eBay listing terms?
Any Advice?
Thanks

Comment: Consider adding the two code snippets, and possibly two screenshots showing the different result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddFixedPriceItem` creates a new listing that does not include any data regarding the previous listing's statistics or sales data. `RelistFixedPriceItem` will create a listing for the product that does include the sales data from the original listing.

The eBay best match search engine uses a listing's sales stats as part of its algorithm to determine search standing. So if your original listing had a good number of views or sales, I would definitely recommend using `ReslistFixedPriceItem`. However, if your previous listings was stagnant for a long time without many views or sales, it might be more advantageous to use `AddFixedPriceItem` instead to give the listing a clean slate.

eBay is always changing their search algorithms, so there is no hard and fast rule here. You really just have to find out what works best for your particular products. Experimentation is key.